# TYPO3 6.2.1 with Bootstrap 3 - backend templates

Tags: templates, typo3

I have setup TYPO3 ver. 6.2.1 and then installed Bootstrap 3 from the Extension Manager and then Get preconfigured distributions.

Works fine.

Now I have navigated to the backend templates and have found em, but have do I add new templates for it, is it the old way or can I just mate a file and drag and drop it into the backend folder and where do I tell it that I have added a new one.

Have someone tried to make new templates in the new TYPO3 with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `TypoScript Object Browser` to have a look at `page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject.*`.

There you can already see all defined templates. To add a new template, add a new `backend layout`. The `uid` of the `backend layout` will be the key for the new `TypoScript` key. Just copy one of the existing entries, name it like your `uid` and give it the path to your template.